# Exercise 5.5.5 in Marker

Tags: model-theory

[image]

Can someone explain why the hint is useful? If $\mathcal{N}_{0}$ is the Skolem hull of $M$ and a countably infinite set of indiscernibles $\mathcal{I}$, my idea is to remove one element of $\mathcal{I}$ each time to create a new Skolem hull $\mathcal{N}_{i+1}$ generated by one less indiscernible element. The problem is that there may be a non-indiscernible element in every $\mathcal{N}_{i}$ that doesn't exist in $\mathcal{M}$ so the equality doesn't hold.

A hint or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, presumably the point is to prove that your "problem" can't actually happen, using the fact that they are indiscernibles.

Comment: I feel like the fact that I is a set of indiscernibles actually makes the problem worse. Because if we make the elements of M constant symbols, then if t(a1, ..., an) != m where m is in M for some a1, ..., an that are indiscernibles, then this negation of equality holds no matter what size n set of indiscernibles we use.

Comment: The situation seems to be more complicated than you’re thinking. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323552/indiscernible-to-create-descending-chain-of-elementary-models